# Book Recommend Differential Geometry of Algebraic Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry

I just want to study Differential Geometry of Algebraic Manifolds.

but I can`t find a book about that.

Is there any good book for studying Differential Geometry of Algebraic Manifolds??

Comment: By "Differential Geometry of Algebraic Manifolds", do you mean  differential algebraic geometry or the differential geometry of algebraic manifolds

Comment: How is the differential geometry of algebraic manifolds not just differential geometry? A high number of basic examples in differential geometry are just algebraic manifolds.

Answer (score 3):

Griffiths and Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" would be a start if you are interested in Kahler geometry, which is the differential geometry in the context of complex algebraic manifolds. Ballmann's "Lectures on Kahler manifolds" is another source. For more sources just google "Kahler manifolds".